# context is returning null when called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am new to objective-c and am having some issues passing variables... I am setting a NSManagedObjectContext within a View Controller but when I try to access it from a different View Controller, it returns null.  The public variable managedObjectContext gets set correctly in myProjectsViewController:

```
    if (document.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal)  {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = document.managedObjectContext;
    _managedObjectContext = context;
    NSLog(@"context = %@",context);
}
```

I then try to access it in myTasksViewController:

```
-(void)setManagedObjectcontext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)managedObjectContext
{
myProjectsViewController *mpvc;
_managedObjectContext = mpvc.managedObjectContext;
}
```

At this point, it always returns null.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading that correctly, it looks as if you are creating a new `myProjectsViewController` instance instead of referencing the object you expect.

Objective-C is an Object Oriented programming language. When your view is initialized it creates an "instance" of the `myProjectsViewController`. The code you show in the `myTasksViewController` is creating another "instance" of `myProjectsViewController`. You would instead need to store the value somewhere such as a singleton or possibly pass the value from the first view controller to the second view controller during the transition.

To try to give an example, let's say we have a blueprint of how to build a 2015 Ford Mustang. I use that blueprint to build a 2015 Ford Mustang and I then set the radio to my favorite station. If you were to take the same blueprints and build another, identical, 2015 Ford Mustang, your Mustang wouldn't have any idea what radio station my Mustang was tuned to, because although built from the same model, they are different instances.

I hope this helps. Someone else may be able to give you a better example. But you might want to dig into object oriented programming a bit to see if that helps you get a concrete idea of classes, objects, and instances of objects.